# Calculating the amount of nights in between two dates in Watson Assistant?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

How can I get the Watson Assistant to calculate the amount of nights in between to set dates?

Exp:

Check-in 2019-07-21 Check-Out: 2019-07-28

I'd also like to know how to set an argument so Watson Assistant doesn't allow same day check-ins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Watson Assistant supports standard methods of the java.util.Date class. You can check [the documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-dates-java-util-date)

2) You can put a comparison condition to check if the two entity values are same or not. 
Eg - `<? @date[0].plusDays(0) == @date[1] ?>`
For more detail, check [this](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-date-time-calculations)